# Помогите составить структуру базы данных

Tags: java, sql, база-данных, mysqli

Вообщем у меня есть два словаря(буквенный и цифровой) формата ключ - значение. Сколько и каких таблиц должно быть, если у слова(ключа) может быть как много значений так и не одного. Сделать одну таблицу СЛОВАРЬ с полями (ключ(буквенный), ключ(цифровой)) и таблицу ЗНАЧЕНИЯ с полями (значение, id словаря). Или же сделать три таблицы: словарь буквенный, словарь цифровой и значения. Или ещё какие варианты есть?

Comment: Доброе утро,
А можно, поподробней, что на входе, какие данные нужно хранить?

Comment: @IgorLiakhov Доброе, хранить нужно обычные строки, по поводу таблицы value не важна их длинна, а вот по поводу ключей, в каждом словаре они разные. Так в цифровом это 5 чисел, а в буквенном 4 буквы. Я думал сделать одну таблицу со всеми типами ключей и таблицу со всеми значениями и внешним ключом к таблице с ключами. Удобно ли будет работать с такой таблицей?

Comment: почитайте про нормализацию данных в SQL, думаю, тогда и ответ найдете. Либо уточните вопрос: как связаны ключи между собой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь, видимо, вам поможет связь "многие ко многим". То есть, таблицы

1. Таблица ключей
2. Таблица значений
3. Таблица связей (ключ - значение)

С такой структурой вы сможете связывать данные первых 2 таблиц в любом порядке

Comment: Хорошо, а как мне потом получить списки только ключей буквенных или наоборот только цифровых если они хранятся в одной таблице

Comment: Либо пометить их в дополнительном столбце (0 - цифра, 1 - буква) либо "на лету" проверять - число это или буква. Первое - правильно, второе - костыль. Также у вас должен быть id в первых 2 таблицах, и в третьей связывать именно по этому id. А для какой конкретно задачи вам это нужно? Может есть более простые решения

Comment: Точно, можно же пометить, благодарю

Comment: Мне нужно реализовать два веб словаря, чтобы это было CRUD приложение. Словарь символьный-перевод, цифровой-перевод